# Asp.net- Mvc Complex Model Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i have two poco class in c# ,  A hotel and rate , it is one to - many relationship 
in hotel create action in controller i have viewbag to populate drop down list as bellow

```
 ViewBag.Hotel_Rate = new SelectList(db.Hotel_Rate, "Id", "Rate");
```

and i have blow code in my view to populate drop down list

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Hotel_Rate", null, new { @Name = "Hotel_Rate.Rate", @id = "Hotel_Rate.Rate" })
```

every thing shoud be right up to here , drowpdown list populate from datebase and is displayed in my view , but when i post the model to controller model is validated but the id of hotel rate is zero ,so i get  EntityValidationErrors'
what is wrong with my binding ? 
i dont want to use any custome model binding class , the default model binder in asp.net is able to handle that , but how?

```
public partial class Hotel
        {
            public Hotel()
            {

            }

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual Hotel_Rate Rate { get; set; }

        }


       public partial class Hotel_Rate
        {
            public Hotel_Rate()
            {
                this.Hotel = new HashSet<Hotel>();
            }

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Rate { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Hotel> Hotel { get; set; }
        }

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Hotel_Rate")] Hotel hotel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Hotels.Add(hotel);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

and the generated html is as below

```
<select name="Hotel_Rate.Rate" id="Hotel_Rate.Rate">
<option value="1">5</option>
<option value="2">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: check the generated html for the select/dropdownlist .. is the value rendered the Id ?

Comment: the value is rendered by id , it is ok .

Comment: Maybe you could show the controller action that processes this.

Comment: Post you html generated for your dropdown (its the name attribute which is important)

Comment: Theres your problem right here ... `name="Hotel_Rate.Rate"` change that to Hotel_Rate

Comment: when i use vs debuger hotel_rate is not null it contain object type of hotel_rate but , its id is 0 and the rate is 1 , or 2 depending on selected value

Comment: The name of the control needs to be `Rate.Rate` or `Rate.ID` (its unclear what your binding to) And you should remove or modify the `Bind(Include..` because you do not have a property named `Hotel_Rate`

Comment: i changed that to Hotel_Rate , now the model is not validated , and Hotel_rate is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues, the naming of the control and the use of the `[Bind(Include ..)]` attribute since you do not have a property named `Hotel_Rate` which contains a property `Rate` (which is what `<select name="Hotel_Rate.Rate" ..>` is trying to bind to).

Use a strongly typed helper to ensure naming issues do not occur

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Rate.Rate, (SelectList)ViewBag.Hotel_Rate)
```

which will render

```
<select name="Rate.Rate" id="Rate_Rate">
  <option value="1">5</option>
  <option value="2">4</option>
</select>
```

Note its unclear exactly what you want to bind to. Your `SelectList` has the value as `ID` and the display text as `Rate` so I actually think you want `m => m.Rate.ID` otherwise your binding either `1` or `2` to the `Rate` property when I think you want to bind `1` or `2` to the `ID` property

Your `Bind` attribute should be

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Rate")] Hotel hotel)
```

but since you have included all properties of `Hotel` in the `Include` list, its pointless and can be deleted altogether.

Comment: thank you , your answer is right , but problem exist somewhere else , the i add ((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception).EntityValidationErrors to watch windows in visual studio to see the error , , Description field is required . it was the problem , thanks . it looks visual studio is trying to create new rate object . i hate Microsoft technology always always lots of problem for start up . try it . it doesn't work dear stephen.

Comment: Well you have a property `Rate` or type `Hotel_Rate` so of course the framework has to create the object (how else could you bind a property to it) and if `Description` is required, then validation will fail since you not binding anything to `Description`. Its always best to use a view model to overcome these sorts of issues.

Comment: it is very clear what i am binding to . i am binding my dropdownlist to a Rate object and i want my hotel to have a rate object . i am not trying to create rate object here . what is unclear about binding ?

Comment: @user2135872, No you are not (and can't) bind to a `Rate` object. A `<select>` control returns a primitive value (`int`, `string` etc.) **not** a complex object such as `Hotel_Rate`. You can only post back one of the properties of `Rate` (`ID`, `Name` or `Description`), not all 3 and it only makes sense to post back the `ID` so you can fetch the rate object from the database if you need it.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke ,  model binding allows you to map HTTP request data with a model , so if i am supposed to get the id by reques.form and retrieve related object from database by that and then add retrieved object   to new object and save my dbcontext , what is the point of binding?

Comment: Your only posting back one property of `Rate`. How do you expect the `DefaultModelBinder` to know what the other 2 properties are? And the point of model binding to to bind the properties you post back, not to guess what the values are of properties you don't post back